Expected value for Deal or No Deal Cases
I have seen calculations for the expected value that a contestant could possibly win on Deal or No Deal. But I am curious about the expected number of case holders who correctly guess the value of their cases. People on the show holding the other 25 cases typically try to guess the money value of the case they have. It appears initially to be a simple binomial distribution but the complication is that with each guess the sample size changes. Just wondering about how to go about this- should I try a standard probabilistic method or a Bayesian approach?

Please explain the rules of the game, or provide a link to a site that explains them.

How is someone unfamiliar with the game supposed to knowledgeably respond to your posted question?

Deal or No deal, 26 cases, maybe it is based on this game-TV-show  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deal_or_No_Deal_(American_game_show), but in this game, there is only 1 player.
